# Pegar dados de uma página e passar para o banco de dados

Tags: mysql, python, whatsapp

Eu quero fazer sorteios via WhatsApp. Para participar, a pessoa enviaria uma mensagem com o nome para o número que vou anunciar e ela recebe a resposta de confirmação e do número do token.

Eu queria que o bot pegasse o número de telefone e nome, salvasse em um banco de dados MySQL e retornasse a resposta a ela. Porém, o número do token seria o id da linha na tabela onde os dados dela foram salvos no MySQL. Como isso poderia ser feito?

Answer (score 1):

```
from app.mac import mac, signals
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Unicode
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('mysql://usuario:senha@servidor/banco')
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

class Cupom(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cupons'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    nome = Column(Unicode(200))
    numero = Column(Unicode(100))

Base.metadata.create_all()

@signals.message_received.connect
def handle(message):
    cupom = Cupom(nome=message.text, numero=message.who)
    s = Session()
    s.add(cupom)
    s.commit()
    mac.send_message("Numero do seu cupom: {}".format(cupom.id),
        message.conversation)
```

Só salvar no seu whatsapp framework, na pasta modules, e habilitar no `__init__.py`

Comment: obrigado! vou testar e te falo

Comment: Amigo, qual nome eu salvo?

Comment: um nome que não conflite, tipo `sorteio.py`